# Clean popup window and write new content when click on href in parent window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'function.php',
    success: function(data){
        win = window.open("", "Window", "width=620,height=320,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,resizable=no"); 
        if(win && !win.closed)
        {
            win.document.clear();
            win.document.writeln(data);
            win.document.writeln("<a href='javascript:self.close()'>close window</a>");
            win.focus();
        }  
    }
});
```

`function.php` returns a html table.

In the parent form contains several links, when press each time on the link i need to refresh the content with new values based on the link id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use jQuery to delete the content of the html and body tag:

```
$('body').empty();

$('html').empty();
```

That means, that function.php has to return a complete page or at least the body of a page via AJAX - to be inserted as new content with `win.document.writeln(data);` (like you have it) or `$("body").html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSBin that fixes your problem: http://jsbin.com/pekemecu/3/edit?html,js,output (tested on Google Chrome only)

Your popup wasn't getting cleared because your were calling `getElementsByTagName` on the window object. Instead, you need to call it on the `window.document` object. Also, don't set the html tag's `innerHTML` to blank. If you do this, all your subsequent `writeln` calls will not work.

Also, please declare variables using `var`, otherwise all your variables get dumped into the global scope.